# Docker build for windows:ltsc2019 hangs while Visio installation at configure step

Tags: office365, visio, docker-container, docker-image

I am trying to a create a docker image with base OS as **windows:ltsc2019** and **VISIO** installation. Build command is always getting hanged at below step :-

```
RUN powershell C:\\ODT\\setup.exe /configure C:\\ODT\\Configuration.xml.
```

Docker Set up File:-

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019 AS build

WORKDIR C:\\ODT
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/7/A/27AF1BE6-DD20-4CB4-B154-EBAB8A7D4A7E/officedeploymenttool_16731-20398.exe odtsetup.exe
RUN odtsetup.exe /quiet /norestart /extract:C:\\ODT

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019 AS download

WORKDIR C:\\ODT
COPY --from=build C:\\ODT\\setup.exe .
ADD Configuration.xml .
RUN powershell C:\\ODT\\setup.exe /download C:\\ODT\\Configuration.xml

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019

WORKDIR C:\\ODT
COPY --from=build C:\\ODT\\setup.exe .
COPY --from=download C:\\ODT\\Office .
ADD Configuration.xml .
RUN powershell C:\\ODT\\setup.exe /configure C:\\ODT\\Configuration.xml
```

Configuration File :-

```
<Configuration ID="573f6e84-7a6d-4bfd-bae7-de2ce8e94168">
  <Info Description="microsoft" />
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="32" Channel="MonthlyEnterprise" Version="16.0.16626.20208" MigrateArch="TRUE">
    <Product ID="VisioProRetail">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="SCLCacheOverride" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="FALSE" />
  <Property Name="DeviceBasedLicensing" Value="0" />
  <Updates Enabled="TRUE" />
  <RemoveMSI />
  <AppSettings>
    <Setup Name="Company" Value="microsoft" />
    <User Key="software\microsoft\office\16.0\visio\application" Name="showtemplatepanebydefault" Value="0" Type="REG_SZ" App="visio16" Id="L_PreventShowingNewScreenOnLaunch" />
  </AppSettings>
  <Display Level="Full" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
   <Logging Level="Standard" Path="C:\\ODT\\log.txt"/>
</Configuration>
```

Could you please guide me on the successfull step to get a OS windows image with VISIO installation.